# Keras custom Cell Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor

Tags: tensorflow, keras, keras-layer, invalidargumentexception

I'm trying to implement a custom GRUCell in order to save the values of the r and z gates.
The code is identical to the original keras.layer.recurrent.py

The only differences are that I added two class variables to store the tensors (line 48-49) and a getter method. The tensors are saved at line 189-190 or 235-236

```py
    class GRUCellTweak(Layer):

        def __init__(self, units,
                     activation='tanh',
                     recurrent_activation='sigmoid',
                     use_bias=True,
                     kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                     recurrent_initializer='orthogonal',
                     bias_initializer='zeros',
                     kernel_regularizer=None,
                     recurrent_regularizer=None,
                     bias_regularizer=None,
                     kernel_constraint=None,
                     recurrent_constraint=None,
                     bias_constraint=None,
                     dropout=0.,
                     recurrent_dropout=0.,
                     implementation=2,
                     reset_after=False,
                     **kwargs):
            super(GRUCellTweak, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            self.units = units
            self.activation = activations.get(activation)
            self.recurrent_activation = activations.get(recurrent_activation)
            self.use_bias = use_bias

            self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)
            self.recurrent_initializer = initializers.get(recurrent_initializer)
            self.bias_initializer = initializers.get(bias_initializer)

            self.kernel_regularizer = regularizers.get(kernel_regularizer)
            self.recurrent_regularizer = regularizers.get(recurrent_regularizer)
            self.bias_regularizer = regularizers.get(bias_regularizer)

            self.kernel_constraint = constraints.get(kernel_constraint)
            self.recurrent_constraint = constraints.get(recurrent_constraint)
            self.bias_constraint = constraints.get(bias_constraint)

            self.dropout = min(1., max(0., dropout))
            self.recurrent_dropout = min(1., max(0., recurrent_dropout))
            self.implementation = implementation
            self.reset_after = reset_after
            self.state_size = self.units
            self.output_size = self.units
            self._dropout_mask = None
            self._recurrent_dropout_mask = None
            self.reset_gate_history = []
            self.update_gate_history = []

        def build(self, input_shape):
            input_dim = input_shape[-1]

            if isinstance(self.recurrent_initializer, initializers.Identity):
                def recurrent_identity(shape, gain=1., dtype=None):
                    del dtype
                    return gain * np.concatenate(
                        [np.identity(shape[0])] * (shape[1] // shape[0]), axis=1)

                self.recurrent_initializer = recurrent_identity

            self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_dim, self.units * 3),
                                          name='kernel',
                                          initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                                          regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
                                          constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
            self.recurrent_kernel = self.add_weight(
                shape=(self.units, self.units * 3),
                name='recurrent_kernel',
                initializer=self.recurrent_initializer,
                regularizer=self.recurrent_regularizer,
                constraint=self.recurrent_constraint)

            if self.use_bias:
                if not self.reset_after:
                    bias_shape = (3 * self.units,)
                else:
                    # separate biases for input and recurrent kernels
                    # Note: the shape is intentionally different from CuDNNGRU biases
                    # `(2 * 3 * self.units,)`, so that we can distinguish the classes
                    # when loading and converting saved weights.
                    bias_shape = (2, 3 * self.units)
                self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=bias_shape,
                                            name='bias',
                                            initializer=self.bias_initializer,
                                            regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
                                            constraint=self.bias_constraint)
                if not self.reset_after:
                    self.input_bias, self.recurrent_bias = self.bias, None
                else:
                    # NOTE: need to flatten, since slicing in CNTK gives 2D array
                    self.input_bias = K.flatten(self.bias[0])
                    self.recurrent_bias = K.flatten(self.bias[1])
            else:
                self.bias = None

            # update gate
            self.kernel_z = self.kernel[:, :self.units]
            self.recurrent_kernel_z = self.recurrent_kernel[:, :self.units]
            # reset gate
            self.kernel_r = self.kernel[:, self.units: self.units * 2]
            self.recurrent_kernel_r = self.recurrent_kernel[:,
                                                            self.units:
                                                            self.units * 2]
            # new gate
            self.kernel_h = self.kernel[:, self.units * 2:]
            self.recurrent_kernel_h = self.recurrent_kernel[:, self.units * 2:]

            if self.use_bias:
                # bias for inputs
                self.input_bias_z = self.input_bias[:self.units]
                self.input_bias_r = self.input_bias[self.units: self.units * 2]
                self.input_bias_h = self.input_bias[self.units * 2:]
                # bias for hidden state - just for compatibility with CuDNN
                if self.reset_after:
                    self.recurrent_bias_z = self.recurrent_bias[:self.units]
                    self.recurrent_bias_r = (
                        self.recurrent_bias[self.units: self.units * 2])
                    self.recurrent_bias_h = self.recurrent_bias[self.units * 2:]
            else:
                self.input_bias_z = None
                self.input_bias_r = None
                self.input_bias_h = None
                if self.reset_after:
                    self.recurrent_bias_z = None
                    self.recurrent_bias_r = None
                    self.recurrent_bias_h = None
            self.built = True

        def call(self, inputs, states, training=None):
            h_tm1 = states[0]  # previous memory

            if 0 < self.dropout < 1 and self._dropout_mask is None:
                self._dropout_mask = _generate_dropout_mask(
                    K.ones_like(inputs),
                    self.dropout,
                    training=training,
                    count=3)
            if (0 < self.recurrent_dropout < 1 and
                    self._recurrent_dropout_mask is None):
                self._recurrent_dropout_mask = _generate_dropout_mask(
                    K.ones_like(h_tm1),
                    self.recurrent_dropout,
                    training=training,
                    count=3)

            # dropout matrices for input units
            dp_mask = self._dropout_mask
            # dropout matrices for recurrent units
            rec_dp_mask = self._recurrent_dropout_mask

            if self.implementation == 1:
                if 0. < self.dropout < 1.:
                    inputs_z = inputs * dp_mask[0]
                    inputs_r = inputs * dp_mask[1]
                    inputs_h = inputs * dp_mask[2]
                else:
                    inputs_z = inputs
                    inputs_r = inputs
                    inputs_h = inputs

                x_z = K.dot(inputs_z, self.kernel_z)
                x_r = K.dot(inputs_r, self.kernel_r)
                x_h = K.dot(inputs_h, self.kernel_h)
                if self.use_bias:
                    x_z = K.bias_add(x_z, self.input_bias_z)
                    x_r = K.bias_add(x_r, self.input_bias_r)
                    x_h = K.bias_add(x_h, self.input_bias_h)

                if 0. < self.recurrent_dropout < 1.:
                    h_tm1_z = h_tm1 * rec_dp_mask[0]
                    h_tm1_r = h_tm1 * rec_dp_mask[1]
                    h_tm1_h = h_tm1 * rec_dp_mask[2]
                else:
                    h_tm1_z = h_tm1
                    h_tm1_r = h_tm1
                    h_tm1_h = h_tm1

                recurrent_z = K.dot(h_tm1_z, self.recurrent_kernel_z)
                recurrent_r = K.dot(h_tm1_r, self.recurrent_kernel_r)
                if self.reset_after and self.use_bias:
                    recurrent_z = K.bias_add(recurrent_z, self.recurrent_bias_z)
                    recurrent_r = K.bias_add(recurrent_r, self.recurrent_bias_r)

                z = self.recurrent_activation(x_z + recurrent_z)
                r = self.recurrent_activation(x_r + recurrent_r)

                # tweak to store gate activations 
                self.reset_gate_history.append(r)
                self.update_gate_history.append(z)

                # reset gate applied after/before matrix multiplication
                if self.reset_after:
                    recurrent_h = K.dot(h_tm1_h, self.recurrent_kernel_h)
                    if self.use_bias:
                        recurrent_h = K.bias_add(recurrent_h, self.recurrent_bias_h)
                    recurrent_h = r * recurrent_h
                else:
                    recurrent_h = K.dot(r * h_tm1_h, self.recurrent_kernel_h)

                hh = self.activation(x_h + recurrent_h)
            else:
                if 0. < self.dropout < 1.:
                    inputs *= dp_mask[0]

                # inputs projected by all gate matrices at once
                matrix_x = K.dot(inputs, self.kernel)
                if self.use_bias:
                    # biases: bias_z_i, bias_r_i, bias_h_i
                    matrix_x = K.bias_add(matrix_x, self.input_bias)
                x_z = matrix_x[:, :self.units]
                x_r = matrix_x[:, self.units: 2 * self.units]
                x_h = matrix_x[:, 2 * self.units:]

                if 0. < self.recurrent_dropout < 1.:
                    h_tm1 *= rec_dp_mask[0]

                if self.reset_after:
                    # hidden state projected by all gate matrices at once
                    matrix_inner = K.dot(h_tm1, self.recurrent_kernel)
                    if self.use_bias:
                        matrix_inner = K.bias_add(matrix_inner, self.recurrent_bias)
                else:
                    # hidden state projected separately for update/reset and new
                    matrix_inner = K.dot(h_tm1,
                                         self.recurrent_kernel[:, :2 * self.units])

                recurrent_z = matrix_inner[:, :self.units]
                recurrent_r = matrix_inner[:, self.units: 2 * self.units]

                z = self.recurrent_activation(x_z + recurrent_z)
                r = self.recurrent_activation(x_r + recurrent_r)

                # tweak to store gate activations 
                self.reset_gate_history.append(r)
                self.update_gate_history.append(z)

                if self.reset_after:
                    recurrent_h = r * matrix_inner[:, 2 * self.units:]
                else:
                    recurrent_h = K.dot(r * h_tm1,
                                        self.recurrent_kernel[:, 2 * self.units:])

                hh = self.activation(x_h + recurrent_h)

            # previous and candidate state mixed by update gate
            h = z * h_tm1 + (1 - z) * hh

            if 0 < self.dropout + self.recurrent_dropout:
                if training is None:
                    h._uses_learning_phase = True

            return h, [h]

        def get_config(self):
            config = {'units': self.units,
                      'activation': activations.serialize(self.activation),
                      'recurrent_activation':
                          activations.serialize(self.recurrent_activation),
                      'use_bias': self.use_bias,
                      'kernel_initializer':
                          initializers.serialize(self.kernel_initializer),
                      'recurrent_initializer':
                          initializers.serialize(self.recurrent_initializer),
                      'bias_initializer': initializers.serialize(self.bias_initializer),
                      'kernel_regularizer':
                          regularizers.serialize(self.kernel_regularizer),
                      'recurrent_regularizer':
                          regularizers.serialize(self.recurrent_regularizer),
                      'bias_regularizer': regularizers.serialize(self.bias_regularizer),
                      'kernel_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.kernel_constraint),
                      'recurrent_constraint':
                          constraints.serialize(self.recurrent_constraint),
                      'bias_constraint': constraints.serialize(self.bias_constraint),
                      'dropout': self.dropout,
                      'recurrent_dropout': self.recurrent_dropout,
                      'implementation': self.implementation,
                      'reset_after': self.reset_after}
            base_config = super(GRUCellTweak, self).get_config()
            return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

        def get_gates_history():
            return self.reset_gate_history, self.update_gate_history
```

Model is defined as:

```py
input_tensor = Input(shape=(timesteps, features), name="input")
conv = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=6,use_bias=True,
              strides=1, dilation_rate=1, padding='same')(input_tensor)
b = BatchNormalization()(conv)
cell = GRUCellTweak(512)
s_gru, states = keras.layers.recurrent.RNN(cell, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)(b)
biases = tf.keras.initializers.Constant(value=20.15)
out = Dense(1, activation='linear', name="output", 
            kernel_initializer='truncated_normal', bias_initializer=biases)(s_gru)
model = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=[out])
```

I can train the model, however when I try to get the tensors like this (sample is a Numpy Array):

```py
sample = test_x[7:8, :, :]
pred = model.predict(sample)
rnn = model.layers[-2].cell #select the rnn layer
z, r = rnn.get_gates_history()
print(K.eval(r[0]))
```

I'm getting this stacktrace:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1364     try:
-> 1365       return fn(*args)
   1366     except errors.OpError as e:

9 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _run_fn(feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, options, run_metadata)
   1349       return self._call_tf_sessionrun(options, feed_dict, fetch_list,
-> 1350                                       target_list, run_metadata)
   1351 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _call_tf_sessionrun(self, options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
   1442                                             fetch_list, target_list,
-> 1443                                             run_metadata)
   1444 

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_11' with dtype float and shape [?,1250,2]
     [[{{node input_11}}]]
  (1) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_11' with dtype float and shape [?,1250,2]
     [[{{node input_11}}]]
     [[rnn_5/Sigmoid/_959]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-53-2c38b84327d9> in <module>()
      5 z, r = rnn.get_gates_history()
      6 print(r[0].shape, z[0].shape)
----> 7 print(K.eval(r[0]))
      8 return
      9 sample = test_x[7:8, :, :]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in eval(x)
    701     {{np_implementation}}
    702     """
--> 703     return to_dense(x).eval(session=get_session())
    704 
    705 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in eval(self, feed_dict, session)
    796 
    797     """
--> 798     return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, session)
    799 
    800   def experimental_ref(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py in _eval_using_default_session(tensors, feed_dict, graph, session)
   5405                        "the tensor's graph is different from the session's "
   5406                        "graph.")
-> 5407   return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
   5408 
   5409 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    954     try:
    955       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 956                          run_metadata_ptr)
    957       if run_metadata:
    958         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1178     if final_fetches or final_targets or (handle and feed_dict_tensor):
   1179       results = self._do_run(handle, final_targets, final_fetches,
-> 1180                              feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
   1181     else:
   1182       results = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _do_run(self, handle, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
   1357     if handle is None:
   1358       return self._do_call(_run_fn, feeds, fetches, targets, options,
-> 1359                            run_metadata)
   1360     else:
   1361       return self._do_call(_prun_fn, handle, feeds, fetches)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1382                     '\nsession_config.graph_options.rewrite_options.'
   1383                     'disable_meta_optimizer = True')
-> 1384       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1385 
   1386   def _extend_graph(self):

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_11' with dtype float and shape [?,1250,2]
     [[node input_11 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
  (1) Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_11' with dtype float and shape [?,1250,2]
     [[node input_11 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
     [[rnn_5/Sigmoid/_959]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

Original stack trace for 'input_11':
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
    app.launch_new_instance()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 664, in launch_instance
    app.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelapp.py", line 477, in start
    ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 888, in start
    handler_func(fd_obj, events)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 450, in _handle_events
    self._handle_recv()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 480, in _handle_recv
    self._run_callback(callback, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 432, in _run_callback
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 277, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 283, in dispatcher
    return self.dispatch_shell(stream, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 235, in dispatch_shell
    handler(stream, idents, msg)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/kernelbase.py", line 399, in execute_request
    user_expressions, allow_stdin)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/ipkernel.py", line 196, in do_execute
    res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel/zmqshell.py", line 533, in run_cell
    return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2718, in run_cell
    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2822, in run_ast_nodes
    if self.run_code(code, result):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2882, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-51-5af6297ceb19>", line 3, in <module>
    model = create_model(train_x.shape[1], train_x.shape[2])
  File "<ipython-input-30-e8b0b573d8d5>", line 9, in create_model
    input_tensor = Input(shape=(timesteps, features), name="input")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_layer.py", line 178, in Input
    input_tensor=tensor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_layer.py", line 87, in __init__
    name=self.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 541, in placeholder
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 2619, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops.placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 6669, in placeholder
    "Placeholder", dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 794, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3357, in create_op
    attrs, op_def, compute_device)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 3426, in _create_op_internal
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py", line 1748, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

How can I return z and r gate tensors?

Comment: What's `test_x`?

Comment: Hello!, It's a numpy array with shape (batch_size, timestep, feature)